# Декодирование JSON в массив в языке Go

Tags: массивы, json, golang

Задача:

-декодировать произвольный json массив произвольной вложенности

-поместить его в аналогичный массив Go

-запаковать массив обратно в строку json

Примерно так это устроено в языке PHP - $array = json_decode($RawJsonString);

Ещё раз хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что json нам могут прислать любой

Для примера:

```
{
  "content": { "id": 10, "data": "какая-то строчка" },
  "author" : "%USERNAME%"
}
```

Данный JSON должен быть преобразован в массив типа:

```
println(string(array.content.id)) // == 10
println(string(array.author))     // == Vasya
```

За вечер страданий было достигнуто только выведение строчки из произвольного JSON`а:

```
map[response:map[count:442 
items:[
map[id:4.56239506e+08
artist:Ленинград duration:190
date:1.506616285e+09 
url:https://something 
owner_id:4.07531429e+08
title:Songname genre_id:18
is_licensed:true] etc....
```

Следующим кодом:

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    resp, err := client.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?access_token=&count=6000&v=5.64")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)

    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if dec == nil {
        panic("Failed to start decoding JSON data")
    }

    json_map := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = dec.Decode(&json_map)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n",json_map )
}
```

Ещё нужно это дело уметь запаковать обратно, это я не осилил совсем

В связи с этим, прошу помощи у экспертов по Go
Или, быть может кто знает либу, которая мне позволит сделать всё вышеописанное, альтернативу стандартной encoding/json ?

Comment: Во-первых, у вас не массив, а объект. Во-вторых, какие у вас проблемы возникают с [`encoding/json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder)?

Comment: @ainar-g уже никаких, осталось только с декодированием разобратьсяъ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отличии от PHP, Go — язык со строгой статической типизацией. Значит, если вы хотите получить какие-то объекты, то у них должны быть типы. Так как рассериализацию делает внешняя библиотека, поля у этих типов должны быть экспортированы, то есть начинаться с заглавной буквы.

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

const jsonResponse = `{
  "content": { "id": 10, "data": "какая-то строчка" },
  "author" : "%USERNAME%"
}`

type Content struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Data string `json:"data"`
}

type Response struct {
    Content Content `json:"content"`
    Author  string  `json:"author"`
}

func main() {
    var response Response
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonResponse), &response)

    fmt.Println("author = ", response.Author)
    fmt.Println("content.id = ", response.Content.Id)

    responseJson, _ := json.Marshal(response)
    fmt.Println("Back to JSON:", string(responseJson))
}
```

Пример в работе: https://play.golang.org/p/cpeKai1bsk

Каждый язык и каждый инструмент имеет свое предназначение. Если вам нужно жонглировать со сложными объектами неизвестной структуры или работать с глубокими структурами данных, то Go не обязательно будет подходящим инструментом в том, что касается удобства и скорости разработки. Смиритесь с этим. С другой стороны, если вам нужно сделать многопоточный сервер, то на PHP это будет сделать много сложней, чем на Go.

Подумайте, может быть на PHP вы бы уже решили вашу задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Всё понял. Логично предположить, что если вам в обработчик прислали какой-то JSON - вы уже примерное предполагаете, с какими полями вам придется работать. Но, конкретной структуры - схемы пришедшего ответа у нас ещё нет. Чтобы её построить нам нужно посмотреть, есть ли, например в ответе поле "error". Дальше мы уже можем использовать gjson.Unmarshal()

Или вам нужно просто получить одно значение, которое точно будет в исходной строке( например, если вы пишете преобразователь одного JSON файла в другой)

Для всего этого мы можем использовать GJson ( https://github.com/tidwall/gjson )

Впринципе то же самое, но более громоздко можно сделать и на encoding/json